# Mongodb php searching using _id gives errors

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, bulk, php-mongodb

I want to search _id by using executeQuery mongodb driver php.

Here is my document structure of the **users** collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55ad0bd1032e1b12088b46a8"),
    "email" : "abc@abc.com"
}
```

And my php code is

```
<?php
//Getting object id
$id = new MongoId("55ad0bd1032e1b12088b46a8");
//filtering 
$filter = ['_id' =>$id];

$options = [];

// Adding query
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);

$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery('db.users', $query);
```

when I run it I got following errors

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionException' with message 'unknown
>   operator: $id' in /test.php:27 Stack trace:
>   0 /test.php(27): MongoDB\Driver\Manager->executeQuery('db.users', Object(MongoDB\Driver\Query))
>   1 {main}   thrown in test.php on line 27

Any help?

Comment: It's weird that it is a ConnectionException. Which is line 27?
Also since you're using the MongoDB php extension (and not the Mongo extension) you should use ``ObjectID`` instead of MongoId.
http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-objectid.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Per comment of @Felipe Sulser

The line

```
$id = new MongoId("55ad0bd1032e1b12088b46a8");
```

should be

```
$id = new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId("55ad0bd1032e1b12088b46a8");
```

Now it is working